# Knockout - Fetch Options for Select and select one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

When I load my page i have a `<select>` positioned. I use knockout data-bind to fetch the values as

```
<select data-bind="attr: { id: 'input-' + id(), required: !allowBlank },
                           options: valuesArray,
                           optionsText: 'description',
                           optionsValue: 'itemValue',
                           optionsCaption: 'Select One...',
                           value: value,
                           enable: isEnabled,
                           event: { focus:  $parent.getOptions}"
                    class="form-control" />
```

Right now I'm using the `focus` event because i can't seem to get hold of a event that behaves like `onReady`...

My problems are 2:

1. How can I trigger `$parent.getOptions` as soon as possible? Preferably before user interaction...
2. The property `value` always has a value, how can I set it? I imagine that I will have to w8 for the `$parent.getOptions` to return... or can I "force" it?!? And yes, they key I plan to force will be available in the set of the call mentioned above.

Comment: Why are you trying to populate your options in the on focus event. Is not easier to get and render them from the start?

Comment: @devconcept that is one of my questions... how can I render them from the start?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to populate the options of your select in a given event. In knockout this is accomplished by change the value of an observable, knockout takes care of the rest. You can bind this event to a function and **inside** this function you can call your $parent.getOptions logic. This is an example

```
var exampleVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.valuesArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.value = ko.observable();

    self.getOptions = function () {
        var responseFromTheServer;
        //Make ajax calls in here to get the values and format those to
        //an array in the form [{ description: ..., itemValue: ... }]
        self.valuesArray(responseFromTheServer); 
// In here knockout will update the select in the html with your options
    };

    self.isEnable = ko.observable(true);
    // The rest of your viewmodel ....

}
```

Dont forget to call apply bindings. The html then will look like

```
<select data-bind="attr: { id: 'input-' + id(), required: !allowBlank },
                       options: valuesArray,
                       optionsText: 'description',
                       optionsValue: 'itemValue',
                       optionsCaption: 'Select One...',
                       value: value,
                       enable: isEnabled,
                       event: { focus:  getOptions}"
                class="form-control" />
```

Calling $parent is only used when you have a viewmodel inside a viewmodel or inside an foreach binding. In your case everything is in the same viewmodel so no point in calling $parent.
If you want to trigger this as soon as possible you should call self.getOptions at the end of your viewmodel declaration like this.

```
var exampleVm = function () {
    var self = this;
    ........
    //This will execute as soon the viewmodel is created. 
    //Remember getOptions is just a plain javascript function
    self.getOptions();
}
```

To set a value you need first to have the options populated and later set using the associated observable like this.

```
self.value(myNewValue);
```

Knockout will do nothing if you dont have any options in the select so you have to populate your options first and right after set the value.

**{Edit}**

I forgot to mention if you load your options right from the start you have no need for the focus event anymore. Remove this or the call to the server will be triggered again on focus.